# Query para buscar registros (cliente) SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtro, busqueda, where

estoy intentando realizar una consulta que tenga los siguientes parámetros
1 - Cliente que haya sigo creado antes de la fecha '2021-01-31'
2 - Que las cuentas que tenga asociado ese cliente estén en estado 3,4 y 5 que son cerradas y que sea antes del '2021-01-31'  `ContractStatusId IN (3,4,5)`
3 - que el estado del cliente sea 1 `StatusId=1` 
4 - Que si el cliente cumple con los parametros anteriores y tiene una cuenta asociada que haya sido creada despues del 2021-01-31 entonces me aparezca en la consulta

Por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen podemos ver que el cliente JUAN PEREZ tiene 2 cuentas asociadas, pero ninguna de ellas esta en estado 1 o que alguna de ellas haya sido creada después del 2021-01-31, pero el cliente JOSE GOMEZ, tiene igual 2 cuentas asociadas, una de ellas esta en estado 4 y creada antes del 2021-01-31 pero tiene otra que si esta en estado 1 y fue creada después del 2021-01-31 por lo que ese cliente creo una cuenta después de esa fecha entonces en mi consulta quiero que solo me salga ese cliente

el query que tengo es este

```
SELECT 
c.ClientId,
c.FullnameLocal AS Nombre,
c.StatusId AS EstadoCliente,
c.TaxCode,
c.Created AS FechaCreacionCliente,
ccr.ContractNumber NumeroCuenta,
co.Created AS FechaCreacionCuenta,
co.ContractStatusId AS EstadoCuenta
FROM dbo.Clients c
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerContractRelations ccr ON ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId
INNER JOIN dbo.Contracts co ON co.ContractNumber = ccr.ContractNumber
WHERE c.Created <= '2021-01-31' AND  co.ContractStatusId IN (3,4,5) AND co.Created <= '2021-01-31' AND c.StatusId=1
```

Me cumple todas las condiciones excepto la de que me traiga unicamente clientes que hayan creado cuenta despues del 2021-01-31 pero antes de es fecha no tenga cuenta activas

Si alguien me ayuda porfavor

Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Si he entendido bien quieres los registros de las cuentas cerradas antes del 2021-01-31 y las abiertas después del 2021-01-31 de aquellos clientes creados antes del 2021-01-31 con estado 1 ¿es correcto?

Answer (score 0):

En tu SELECT tienes que te busque donde la cuenta fue creada antes de la fecha cuando deberia buscarte despues de la fecha.

Tu tienes:

```
   co.Created <= Fecha;
```

Y debe ser

```
   co.Created >= Fecha;
```